# how to find authenticated cookies in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am .net Beginner,when the log-in request send from client to server in forms authentication
the server will sends authenticated cookies back to client after successfull log-in ,at every request cookies will sends to server.

so can we see this cookies on browser if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies can be read using this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

I don't think the .NET framework cookies are exposed to the client, but could be wrong.  Some cookies, if a setting is enabled on it (called HttpOnly) are server-only cookies and can't be read on the client.  The name of the cookie is configurable in the web.config's `<form>` element.